# Using Ajax to access an external php file

Tags: php, jquery

so I am trying to access some content in an external php file (not on my domain) however I can browser to the content but I cannot access it via jquery ajax here is my code:

```
function newarticle()
{
var ajax_load = "<img src='images/spiral.gif' align='center' alt='loading...' />";  

//load() functions  
var loadUrl = "http://www.webapp-testing.com/includes/newarticles.php";  
$("#articles").click(function(){  
    $("#pagetitle").html(ajax_load).load("New Articles");
    $("#listarticles").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);  
}); 
}
```

what am i doing incorrect to access this content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only make AJAX requests on the same domain due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Your best bet is to make a server-side (in something like PHP) proxy. You would then make the request on the proxy (which would be on the same server), which would make a request to the page and return the information.

Comment: Like I told you. Make a server-side script to do the request for you and put it on the same domain as your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As Xeon06 mentioned - you can't make cross site requests with AJAX. You can have a look at JSONP though that basically allows you to do it.
 [Link to jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)
[Link to JSONP Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: ...if you can modify the page you are attempting to read from to support JSONP.

Comment: I can modify it I just dont know how to do such

Answer (score 0):

Create your own php file that get the content of the desired url with a curl.
-> http://ch.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php

=> your_php_file.php

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.webapp-testing.com/includes/newarticles.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print $page;

?>
```

In your javascript code, call your_php_file.php

```
function newarticle()
{
var ajax_load = "<img src='images/spiral.gif' align='center' alt='loading...' />";  

//load() functions  
var loadUrl = "your_php_file.php";  
$("#articles").click(function(){  
    $("#pagetitle").html(ajax_load).load("New Articles");
    $("#listarticles").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);  
}); 
}
```